# Are there patterns for "lookbehind filters" in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, iot

I stumbled at a couple of workloads which seem to require filtering data with "lookback" capability - mainly in IoT scenarios, where sensors can produce garbage data, and to detect that it's necessary to look at the previous record of that sensor.

Spark's `filter()` operation is obviously "element-only" - in fact, the RDD as a whole can't know the order of the elements you want it to look behind on. So another approach is needed.

My naive approach would involve keying the RDD on the sensor, repartitioning it so that keys and partitions become one and the same, and sorting all elements for the keys/partition so that they are in temporal order. Then we can filter with a user function and maybe emit the data back so that the rest of the pipeline can deal with it as it wishes.

However, this looks heavyweight and likely inefficient. Is there a more idiomatic way?

**Summary: Is there a Spark-related design pattern to deal with filtering tasks which need to "lookback" at the previous element of a sequence?**